# Checking Google ReCaptcha for success on backend

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a contact form that is performing validation on the back end, what I want to check for is if the user has successfully completed the captcha or not and if not print an error message.

Currently, I am getting an error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: g-recaptcha-response in /var/www/html/mangoForm.php on line 99
```

So it isn't printing the error message that is in the JSON:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"captcha":"ReCaptcha is required."}}
```

**Line 99:**

```
$captcha = checkCaptcha($formData['g-recaptcha-response']);
```

**Code Block in Question:**

```
    if (!empty($validationMSG)) {
        return $validationMSG;        
    }
    else {
        $captcha = checkCaptcha($formData['g-recaptcha-response']);
        if(!$captcha['isSuccess']){
        $validationMSG['captcha'] = 'ReCaptcha is required.';

        return $validationMSG;
        }

        //End of Validation Function
}
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php
//show errors - enable this
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Var Dump (Debugging)
//var_dump($_POST);

//Load Required Components
require_once 'src/recaptcha_autoload.php';
require_once "functions.php";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

function validate($formData)
{

    // Initiate Array

    $validationMSG = array(); // array to hold validation errors

    $pname_exp = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,20}/';

    if (!isset($formData['firstName'])) {
        $validationMSG['firstName'] = 'First Name is required.';
    }elseif (!preg_match($pname_exp, $formData['firstName'])){
         $validationMSG['firstName'] = 'First Name is not valid.';
    }

    // Validate lastName
    if (!isset($formData['lastName'])) {
        $validationMSG['lastName'] = 'Last Name is required.';
    }

    // Check RegEx for Last Name
    elseif (!preg_match($pname_exp, $formData['lastName'])) {
        $validationMSG['lastName'] = 'Last Name is not valid.';
    }

    // Validate companyName
    if (!isset($formData['companyName'])) {
        $validationMSG['companyName'] = 'Company Name is required.';
    }

    // Validate companyAddress
    if (!isset($formData['companyAddress'])) {
        $validationMSG['companyAddress'] = 'Company Address is required.';
    }

    // Validate state
    if (!isset($formData['state'])) {
        $validationMSG['state'] = 'State is required.';
    }

    // Validate city
    if (!isset($formData['city'])) {
        $validationMSG['city'] = 'City is required.';
    }

    // Validate Zipcode - If Field is Empty
    if (!isset($formData['zipcode'])) {
        $validationMSG['zipcode'] = 'Zipcode is required.';
    }

    // Validate emailAddress
    if (!isset($formData['emailAddress'])) {
        $validationMSG['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';
    }

    // Check if emailAddress is a valid email address
    elseif (!filter_var($formData['emailAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $validationMSG['emailAddress'] = 'Email address is not valid.';
    }

    //Validate phoneNumber
    if (!isset($formData['phoneNumber'])) {
        $validationMSG['phoneNumber'] = 'Phone Number is required.';
    }

    //Validate phoneNumber
    elseif (preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $formData['phoneNumber'])) {
        $validationMSG['phoneNumber'] = 'Must be a valid phone number.';
    }

    var_dump($formData);
    // Validate message
    if (!isset($formData['message'])) {
        $validationMSG['message'] = 'Message is required.';
    }

    if (!empty($validationMSG)) {
        return $validationMSG;        
    }
    else {
        $captcha = checkCaptcha($formData['g-recaptcha-response']);
        if(!$captcha['isSuccess']){
        $validationMSG['captcha'] = 'ReCaptcha is required.';

        return $validationMSG;
        }

        //End of Validation Function
}
}

function checkCaptcha($g_recaptcha_response)
{
    $recaptcha_secret_key = 'REDACTED';
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptcha_secret_key);
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($g_recaptcha_response, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    return [
        'isSuccess' =>  $resp->isSuccess(),
        'errorCodes' => $resp->getErrorCodes(),
        ];
}

function sendMail($formData)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    // Server settings

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.server.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@server.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'REDACTED'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to

    // Recipients

    $mail->setFrom('user@server.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('user@server.com', 'Joe User'); // Add a recipient

    // Content

    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New Message from Contact Form';

    // prepare email body

    $body_message = "";
    $body_message.= "Sender IP: " . get_client_ip() . "<br />";

    // @todo: make the other rows the same way, i.e. $formData['key'];

    $body_message.= "First Name: " . $formData['firstName'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "Last Name: " . $formData['lastName'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "Company Name: " . $formData['companyName'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "Company Address: " . $formData['companyAddress'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "City: " . $formData['city'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "State: " . $formData['state'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "Sender email: " . $formData['emailAddress'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "Sender Phone: " . $formData['phoneNumber'] . "<br />";
    $body_message.= "\n\n" . $formData['message'];
    $mail->Body = $body_message;
    $mail->send();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// process

//this will be our whole response (jsoned later)
$response = [
    //we'll change these later, possibly:
    'success' => false,
    'errors' => [],
  //  'message' => 'There has been an issue sending your message!!!!',//could be an "OK" error message as well, depends on the 'success' key.
];

// Copy $_POST to $formData
//$formData = $_POST;
//$formData = json_decode($_POST, true);
$formData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

//validate
$errors = validate($formData);
if(!empty($errors)){
   $response['success']  = false;
   $response['errors']  = $errors;

}else {//it's ok
    //send it
    try{
        sendMail($formData);
        //Print Success Message
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Message was Sent!';
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // Print phpMailer Error Message
        $response['success']  = false;
        $response['message'] = 'There has been an issue sending your message';

    }

}

echo json_encode($response);

exit;
```

How I can achieve where the PHP script checks for a successful response from Google ReCaptcha and either permits the script to go on further in the event of a success or print an error message?

**EDITED JS:**

```
document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
//create variable for contact form url
var formURL = 'mangoForm.php';
//prevent default submission
event.preventDefault();
//define form fields
var mangoForm = {
    'firstName'              : document.querySelector('input[name=firstName]').value,
    'lastName'             : document.querySelector('input[name=lastName]').value,
    'companyName'       : document.querySelector('input[name=companyName]').value,
    'companyAddress'       : document.querySelector('input[name=companyAddress]').value,
    'city'       : document.querySelector('input[name=city]').value,
    'state'       : document.querySelector('select[name=state]').value,
    'zipcode'       : document.querySelector('input[name=zipcode]').value,
    'emailAddress'       : document.querySelector('input[name=emailAddress]').value,
    'phoneNumber'       : document.querySelector('input[name=phoneNumber]').value,
    'message'       : document.querySelector('input[name=message]').value,
}


//define request variable
var formRequest = new Request(formURL, {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify(mangoForm), 
    headers: {
        "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
      }
});

//fetch
fetch(formRequest)
//console.log(formRequest)
.then(function(formResponse) {
    return formResponse.json();
  })
.then(function(data) {
    //handle server responses
    if ( ! data.success) {
    //handle error messages
        //handle error message for firstName
        //console.log(data);
        if (data.errors.firstName && !document.querySelector('#firstName-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("firstName-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.firstName;
            document.getElementById("firstName-group").append(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for lastName
        if (data.errors.lastName && !document.querySelector('#lastName-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("lastName-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.lastName;
            document.getElementById("lastName-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for companyName
        if (data.errors.companyName && !document.querySelector('#companyName-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("companyName-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.companyName;
            document.getElementById("companyName-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for companyAddress
        if (data.errors.companyAddress && !document.querySelector('#companyAddress-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("companyAddress-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.companyAddress;
            document.getElementById("companyAddress-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for city
        if (data.errors.city && !document.querySelector('#city-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("city-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.city;
            document.getElementById("city-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for state
        if (data.errors.state && !document.querySelector('#state-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("state-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.state;
            document.getElementById("state-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for zipcode
        if (data.errors.zipcode && !document.querySelector('#zipcode-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("zipcode-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.zipcode;
            document.getElementById("zipcode-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for emailAddress
        if (data.errors.emailAddress && !document.querySelector('#emailAddress-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("emailAddress-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.emailAddress;
            document.getElementById("emailAddress-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for phoneNumber
        if (data.errors.phoneNumber && !document.querySelector('#phoneNumber-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("phoneNumber-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.phoneNumber;
            document.getElementById("phoneNumber-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
        }
        //handle errors for message
        if (data.errors.message && !document.querySelector('#message-group .help-block')) {
            document.getElementById("message-group").classList.add("has-error");
            let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
            helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
            helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.message;
            document.getElementById("message-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
            }
        // handle errors for captcha ---------------
        if (data.errors.captcha) {
            swal({
                title: "Error!",
                text: data.errors.captcha,
                icon: "error",
            });
        }
        // handle errors for phpmailer ---------------
        if (data.message) {
            swal({
                title: "Error!",
                text: data.message,
                icon: "error",
                });
        }   
    if (data.success) {
    swal({
        title: "Success!",
        text: data.message,
        icon: "success",
        });
//document.getElementById("form").reset();  
}
}
});
})
```

Comment: Please check that recaptcha is added to your form. Next please check that it initilizes at well. Finally, could you show output of `var_dump($formData);`? Also html for form will be useful.

Comment: @marv255 recaptcha is added to the form. var_dump results in nothing much.

Comment: Error from your message means that there is no recaptcha in your response. We should check in which place it was lost.

Comment: @marv255 I will add the JS files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @marv255 there actually is no captcha data in your request apparently.

So try adding this:

```
'g-recaptcha-response' : grecaptcha.getResponse()
```

Just below

```
'message' : document.query ...
```

In your js file.